# How to integrate errbit and gitlab issue tracker?

Tags: gitlab, errbit

How to integrate errbit and gitlab issue tracker?

What should I fill to "Api Token" and "Ticket Project ID (use Number)" fileds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Token can be found in your Gitlab user profile page, on the Account tab.

For Ticket Project ID - use url like this:

```
https://yourgitlabserver.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=yourprivatetoken
```

and you will get a response with all projects data and there you can find the IDs.